# jquery post value on toggle action

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the html code:

```
        <div class="magic-container">               
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" placeholder="Select category ..." />
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style= "margin-top: -10px !important;">
                      <li id="one"><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                      <li id="two"><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                      <li id="three"><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                     <li id="four"><a href="#">Business</a></li>

                      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>

                <span class="flip">
        <a href="#" class="mirror1"> FLIP </a> 
                </span>
            </div>
       </div>
        <div class="magic-bar">
            <span id="rating-slider" class="ui-slider-range"></span>
            <span class="flip">
                <a href="#" class="mirror2"> FLIP </a>
            </span>
        </div>
```

When `FLIP` with mirror1 clicked, I want to post `fc1` and when `FLIP` with mirror2 is clicked I want to post `fc2`.

Here is my code to perform this:

```
        $(".flip").on('click', function() {
            $(".magic-bar").toggle();
                    $.ajax({

                            url: "invite_db.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {"flipClick": 'fc1'},
                            success: function(data) {
                                $(".articleContent").html(data);

                                //setInterval("messageDisable()", 5000);
                            }
                        });

            $(".magic-container").toggle();
                    $.ajax({

                            url: "invite_db.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {"flipClick": 'fc2'},
                            success: function(data) {
                                $(".articleContent").html(data);

                                //setInterval("messageDisable()", 5000);
                            }
                        });

        });
```

But when I click on `FLIP` both the values get posted and page response remains same. What is the logic mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you only get the click on class flip, insted what anchor is clicked.

Try:

```
 $(".flip a").on('click', function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('mirror1'))
      {
        $(".magic-bar").toggle(); $(".magic-container").toggle(); 
        $.ajax({
        url: "invite_db.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"flipClick": 'fc1'},
        success: function(data) {
        $(".articleContent").html(data);

        //setInterval("messageDisable()", 5000);
        }
        });
       }
      else
        {
            $(".magic-container").toggle(); $(".magic-bar").toggle();
            $.ajax({
            url: "invite_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"flipClick": 'fc2'},
            success: function(data) {
            $(".articleContent").html(data);
            //setInterval("messageDisable()", 5000);
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but when I click on `FLIP` once, toggle does not take place and FLIP part disappears

Comment: sorry, FLIP part appears but toggle has some issue

Comment: thanks, you missed small thing. In `if` adding this `                            $(".magic-bar").toggle();
                            $(".magic-container").toggle();

` and in `else` adding this `                   $(".magic-container").toggle();
                                    $(".magic-bar").toggle();

`

Comment: @Programming_crazy nop problem. I was updating the answerd whit that.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply submitting both values when clicking any DOM object with class "flip". I read your code like this:

```
$(".flip").on('click', function() {
    $(".magic-bar").toggle();
    $.ajax({ data: {"flipClick": 'fc1'} /* ... */);
    $(".magic-container").toggle();
    $.ajax({ data: {"flipClick": 'fc2'} /* ... */);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
There is no conditional logic in your code

For instance you need to check if the closest anchor tag
of the flip click has class mirror1 or mirror2 then based
on that you will do one of the two calls and toggle
```

Something like this

```
$(".flip a").on('click', function() {
if($(this).hasClass('mirror1')){
}

if($(this).hasClass('mirror2')){
}
}
```

Comment: thanks but still it has issue, in this case toogle does not works. Both FLIP appears. I followed answer by Freak